# Really slow login on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, ubuntu-18.04, login-screen

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new computer.

The OS is dual booted with Windows 10. The OS is installed on SSD, and so the boot takes about 10 seconds.

When I get to the login window, and after typing my password, it takes around 35 seconds to get the desktop (purple screen meanwhile).

Tried and failed to find the logs of this process to see what's taking so long.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777244/slow-boot-and-login-times-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspected the problem is with Nvidia GPU. checked dmesg and found there are really a lot of timeouts to the "nouveau" driver.
used [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu) guide to update my driver to more compatible Nvidia driver. Boot now takes ~7 seconds, and login after inserting password ~7-8 more.

Comment: Isn't 7 seconds for boot and 7 seconds for login still quite long? Especially for Linux on an SSD. Have you had any other problems? Asking because I'm dealing with something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is exactly 7 seconds, but it seemed fine for me. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Environment

Ubuntu 20.10
Gnome (3.38.1) and Budgie Desktops

Problem:

Slow UI Lagging and sometimes unresponsive
Log out or shutdown takes too long, etc.

Changed the display manager from lightdm to gdm3 and the problems vanished!

To check what display manager you are running issue the following command from the terminal:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Or

```
systemctl status display-manager.service
```

To change you display manager use the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure [NAME OF DISPLAY MANAGER]
```

I wanted gdm3, so I issued the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Note, the above command assumed you have gdm3 installed. If not, then install it and then issue:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

You may get an error, ignore it and restart.

You should be good to go.

Comment: some code formatting with backticks would help the readability here A LOT